# useEffect reverse animation is not shown

Tags: react-native, animation, react-hooks, use-effect

### Problem:

Currently, I am struggling with the `useEffect` Hook together with `Animated.timing`. Somehow the reverse animation is not shown. The toggle just jumps back (see gif below). Confusingly, the animation callback is successfully called.

**Wanted behavior:** The slider should animate back and forth smoothly, when the active prop is changed.

[image: Animation]

### Code

**Slider**:

```
const Slider = ({sliderWidth, circleHeight, active, onToggle}) => {
    const transformX = new Animated.Value(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('only run when active changed', transformX);
      const value = active ? sliderWidth-circleHeight: 0;
      console.log('value', value);
        Animated.timing(transformX, {
          toValue: value,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }).start(() => console.log('animation done'));
    }, [active, transformX, sliderWidth, circleHeight]);

    return (
      <View style={{position: 'absolute',width: sliderWidth+10, backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomLeftRadius: 8, borderBottomRightRadius: 8, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{width: sliderWidth, borderRadius: sliderWidth/2, borderWidth: 1, height: circleHeight,justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 8, marginBottom: 8, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 11}}> {active ?  "Pickup" : "Delivery"} </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onToggle} style={{position: 'absolute', left:0,  transform: [{translateX: transformX}]}}>
          <View style={{height: circleHeight-2, width: circleHeight-2, borderRadius: circleHeight/2-1, backgroundColor: 'orange' }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
};
```

**App:**

```
export default function App() {
  const sliderWidth = WIDTH/3;
  const circleHeight = 30;
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Slider sliderWidth={sliderWidth} circleHeight={circleHeight} onToggle={() => setActive(!active)} active={active}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

### Snack

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/useeffect-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really simple, you shall use `transformX` as state instead. Honestly, I don't know what causes the issue but this is a problem there.

```
const Slider = ({sliderWidth, circleHeight, active, onToggle}) => {
  const [transformX] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(0));
...
```

Comment: What a rookie mistake. Thank you very much